# Help with using fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a homework question to find the integral of an unknown function in the interval [-1,3].

To help me do this I've been given a censored graph with has the function f(x) and its anti derivative F(x). I also know that the function is even.

I can work out that f(-1) = f(1) = 2, and so the interval [-1,1] would have an area of 4, however i'm not too sure how to work out the remaining interval, only that I am required to use the FTC somehow.

Any guidance/advise would be appreciated greatly :)

[image: The info I've been given:]

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-1}^3f(x)dx = \int_{-1}^1f(x)dx + \int_{1}^3f(x)dx$, by properties of integrals. You already have figured out what $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx$ is. Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\int_{1}^3f(x)dx = F(3) - F(1)$. Can you use the graph to find what $\int_{1}^3f(x)dx$ is?

Comment: oh wow, that was staring me in the face the whole time ahaha

Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!